# Monitor color after installation under windows

Tags: windows, wubi, windows-vista

I have installed the newest Ubuntu by wubi, and after then my monitor is not showing the colors correctly. It seems like it were 8 bit instead of 32.

Since then I have uninstalled Ubuntu, and reinstalled Windows (Vista) but the colors are still wrong.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

This seems more like to be an hardware issue than a software one.

If you have tried with 2 different systems and the same effect is present I would say there is something wrong with your hardware configuration or a defect graphics card.

You should take it to a computer shop for a repair if you are not confident or don't have the correct tools to further investigate the problem.